# Invalid argument in Google Actions regarding noInputPrompts

Tags: json, actions-on-google, chatbot

I am getting the following error in the Google Actions console and can't seem to work out where I'm going wrong. I've tried to use this [link](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse#inputprompt) for guidance. If remove the "noInputPrompts" section then the response works as expected.Any ideas please?:

```
API Version 2: Failed to parse JSON response string with 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' error: "(expected_inputs[0].input_prompt.no_input_prompts[0]) simpleResponse: Cannot find field." HTTP Status Code: 200.
```

My response looks like this:

```
"expectedInputs": [
    {
      "possibleIntents": [
        {
          "intent": "actions.intent.TEXT"
        }
      ],
      "inputPrompt": {
        "richInitialPrompt": {
          "items": [
            {
              "simpleResponse": {
                "textToSpeech": "test",
                "displayText": "test"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "noInputPrompts": [
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "Test",
              "displayText": "Test"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: You have tagged this question "dialogflow", but you're talking about the Actions on Google simulator. Can you update your question to clarify what you're trying to do - are you responding to a Dialogflow request or are you building your action with actions.json? Can you provide more background?

Comment: Sorry, Dialogflow is involved so I put  the wrong tag in, I've changed it now. We use  Dialogflow as the NLP and  Google assistant amongst other channels as a dumb terminal. Microsoft bot framework  is in the centre of all this and acts as a coordinator between all the channels and Dialogflow.  Request and responses get transformed to the relevant format for the channel in every turn . My question is specific to Google Action so the other tools aren't in scope of this question  unless I'm mistaken.